# Azure DC/OS cluster. How to change SSH RSA public key

Tags: azure, dcos, azure-container-service

I'm new in Azure and DC/OS. I deployed a DC/OS cluster using the next document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-deployment. What should I do in case I want change SSH RSA public key   which I used in deploying? I couldn't find a document with description such situation.

After deploying a DC/OS cluster I have a resource group which contains virtual machine with name like dcos-master-* . I can change public key for this virtual machine using azure web portal: resourcegroup->'dcos-master-* '->Reset password. But as I understand it's not enough. I see also  that my resource group contains virtual machine scale sets like dcos-agent-private-* and dcos-agent-public-*. But I can't find how to reset passwords there.

Explain me please what should I do in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do in case I want change SSH RSA public key which I used
>   in deploying?

Sorry, I have not find how to change the public key of VMSS, I will do some search, if I get anything new, I'll keep you updated.

As a workaround, we can **add** a new public key to VMSS, here is the script:

```
$vmssName = "dcos-agent-private-EAF6BCA8-vmss0"
$vmssResourceGroup = "dcos"
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $vmssResourceGroup -VMScaleSetName $vmssName
Add-AzureRmVmssSshPublicKey -VirtualMachineScaleSet $VMSS -KeyData "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAr1ftAx4QhtzAeqei9ukw32nrM8kmB6t2UVdBpuUjAeBAI3/cln/0vmekCt2OPJof5/mdaMTYoMleMsPxQWcm19fZviiMS0rkmLU9qwTeJf8+T8RWEUB75wRH5aDdrit1eYZ9bwJGL1LbkECKWoB02HZGLRH24Z5BLLXCkXjGI8LTLTTZobAnM4EC1QGMCsuMUl0mlhchaK0yQifx+GHOsbFuqe+E40akAzzh7tt+O4I/TjigrE4YHUJlmGNlY3grXFPE5oaszzb97/yyglt1cW2KucjAI4qm7ZTQ6wz5asW8IoN+jya4h2O4Au0ymNVgw1EQG1p8UJ2qByyxxJNMSw==" -Path "/home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Here is the result:

[image]

By the way, if you don't want user can use your original public key to login VMSS instance, we can **login** this instance and **delete** the original public key in `authorized_key`.

```
jason@dcos-agent-public-EAF6BCA8000001:~$ cd .ssh/
jason@dcos-agent-public-EAF6BCA8000001:~/.ssh$ ls
authorized_keys
jason@dcos-agent-public-EAF6BCA8000001:~/.ssh$ cat authorized_keys 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAr1ftAx4QhtzAeqei9ukw32nrM8kmB6t2UVdBpuUjAeBAI3/cln/0vmekCt2OPJof5/mdaMTYoMleMsPxQWcm19fZviiMS0rkmLU9qwTeJf8+T8RWEUB75wRH5aDdrit1eYZ9bwJGL1LbkECKWoB02HZGLRH24Z5BLLXCkXjGI8LTLTTZobAnM4EC1QGMCsuMUl0mlhchaK0yQifx+GHOsbFuqe+E40akAzzh7tt+O4I/TjigrE4YHUJlmGNlY3grXFPE5oaszzb97/yyglt1cW2KucjAI4qm7ZTQ6wz5asW8IoN+jya4h2O4Au0ymNVgw1EQG1p8UJ2qByyxxJNMSw==
```

**Update**:
we can use this command to list public key.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Hi, thank u for your detailed reply. I've done it. But I still can't connect to my agens from master node. May be I should do something more?

Comment: @Andryusha2006 Can you find the public Key have added to this VMSS, we can use `Get-AzureRmVmss` to list it, and we can see two public keys in it.  After that, we should copy our private key to master `~/.ssh/` and make sure the key permission is 600, about how to upload private to master node, here a similar case, please refer to it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638792/how-to-login-into-dc-os-slave-through-master/43647929#43647929

Comment: I don't understand how I can see it using Get-AzureRmVmss

Comment: @Andryusha2006 please run this command to list public key `$a = get-azurermvmss -ResourceGroupName resourcename -VMScaleSetName vmssname  $a.VirtualMachineProfile.OsProfile.LinuxConfiguration.Ssh.PublicKeys`

Comment: @Andryusha2006 I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: I see my key in list. But still can't connect. I'm connecting using putty and and pageagent key list as in azure documentation to master node and I can't connect to my node: ssh 10.0.0.4 - Permission denied (publickkey).

Comment: @Andryusha2006 you can follow this link to set private key in master node, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638792/how-to-login-into-dc-os-slave-through-master/43647929#43647929  please check it,

Comment: Hi, Jason Ye - MSFT, Sorry, my test subscription is over now and I can't check it. May be I'll try it in future if my company decide to use this technologies. But I 'd suggest the azure team to work at this case and to add a description in details to documentation. I beleive that It's an important case.

Comment: @Andryusha2006 Thank you for your suggestion:)  it's very import to Azure. I had test in my lab, we can add public key to vmss, and use this key to login vm, maybe you can try it in future.  Also if it helpful, please don't forget to accept it as answer, thanks.